# PhpStorm groups SCSS/CSS files ignoring my configuration

Tags: html, css, sass, phpstorm, transpiler

I am running PhpStorm 2016.3.2 (I believe it is the current latest).

Since I've updated to this version, `css` files are always grouped / nested under their `scss` source files in the project tree, regardless if I have a SCSS watcher or not.

I've tried creating a completely empty new project, with no file watchers whatsoever, and manually created two files: `test.scss` and `test.css`. Immediately, the `test.css` got grouped under the `test.scss`.

Furthermore (in another project), I am using a custom transpiler, which creates a `x.html` file for each `x.scss` file in addition to the `x.css` file. However, no matter what I set in the *Output paths to refresh* field, PhpStorm will always group the CSS file, and only the CSS file under the SCSS node.

I am trying to make it also group the HTML file under that node, but ideally I want to know why is it doing any grouping at all when there are no file watchers?

I do want to point out that this was NOT an issue in the previous version.

Is there some hidden setting I am missing, is it a bug or is it a mandatory new "feature"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some hidden setting I am missing,

No.

> is it a bug or is it a mandatory new "feature"?

It's a new feature -- file nesting no longer relies on presence of File Watcher (and the need to run it to have files actually nested).

<s>**At the moment** it's implemented as [hard-coded list of rules](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21873#comment=27-1515879) which you cannot modify (but you may try and suggest other rules and why they will be good).</s>

**UPDATE:** The list of nesting rules is fully customizable since **2017.2** version. You can access those rules [via cog icon in Project View panel](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17977#focus=streamItem-27-2197872.0-0) where you may add your own or even disable such nesting.

[image]